# How to update state of one component in another in react class component. Save Functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to update state of one component in another in react class component.

I have two class in reacts.

MyComponent and MyContainer.

```
export default class MyContainer extends BaseComponent{
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props, {
            status : false, 
            nameValue :"",
            contentValue : ""
        });
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log(this.state.status);
    };
    save = () => {
        console.log("Hello I am Save");
        let obj: object = {
            nameValue: this.state.nameValue, // here I am getting empty string
            templateValue: this.state.contentValue
        };
        // API Call
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComponent
                    nameValue = {this.state.nameValue} 
                    contentValue = {this.state.contentValue} 
                ></MyComponent>   
                <div >
                    <button  type="button"  onClick={this.save} >Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

MyComponent

```
export default class MyComponent extends BaseComponent{
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props, {});
        this.state = {
            nameValue : props.nameValue ? props.nameValue : "",
            contentValue : props.contentValue ? props.contentValue : "",
            status : false
            
           
        }
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log("MOUNTING");
    };

    fieldChange = (id:String, value : String) =>{
        if(id === "content"){
            this.setState({nameValue:value});
        }else{
            this.setState({contentValue:value});
        }
    }
     

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input id="name" onChange={(e) => {this.fieldChange(e)}}></input>
                    <input  id = "content"  onChange={(e) => {this.fieldChange(e)}} ></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

In MyComponent I have placed two input field where on change I am changing the state.

Save button I have in MyContainer. In save button I am not able to read the value of MyComponent. What is the best way to achieve that.

Comment: How are you calling `fieldChange` and how are you calling `save`?

Comment: @NickParsons little update in question. `save` calling in click of save button in MyCompoent and `onchange` in MyContainer class while changing input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be updating your state in `MyContainer` for `save` to have visibility of the state changes. Each component gets its own state, which makes `MyComponent`'s state unique to that of `MyContainer`. What you should be doing is keeping the state in your parent/container component, and then passing it down as props (rather than duplicating it in your child). To do this, move  `fieldChange` up to the `MyContainer` function, and remove the duplicate `nameValue` and `contentValue` state within `MyComponent`. See code commennts for further details:

```js
export default class MyContainer extends BaseComponent{
    ... 

    fieldChange = (id:String, value : String) =>{
        if(id === "content"){
            this.setState({nameValue: value});
        } else {
            this.setState({contentValue: value});
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyComponent
                    nameValue={this.state.nameValue} 
                    contentValue={this.state.contentValue}
                    onFieldChange={this.fieldChange} /* <---- Pass the function down to `MyComponent` */
                /> 
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then in `MyComponent`, call `this.props.onFieldChange`:

```js
export default class MyComponent extends BaseComponent{
    // !! this constructor can be removed as no state is being initialized anymore !!
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        // removed state as we're using the state from `MyContainer`
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log("MOUNTING");
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input id="name" onChange={(e) => {this.props.fieldChange(e)}} /> /* <--- Change to `this.props.fieldChange()`. `<input />` is a self-closing tag.
                    <input  id = "content"  onChange={(e) => {this.props.fieldChange(e)}} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Some additional notes:

- If your component doesn't use `this.props.children`, then you should call it as `<MyComponent ... props ... />` not `<MyComponent ... props ...></MyComponent>`
- Your if-statement in your `fieldChange` looks reversed and should be checking `if(id === "name")`. I'm assuming this is an error in your question.
- You're only passing one argument to `fieldChange` in your example code. I'm again assuming this in an error in your question.